# How can I jQuery POST multiple parameters from a single object selected from a HTML.DropDownList?

Tags: jquery, html, razor

I am using

`@Html.DropDownList("Items", new SelectList(Model.Items, "ItemID", "ItemDisplayName"))`

to render a select list. In my jQuery I am POSTing the selected value (ItemID). However, I need to post more values than that from the chosen Item object. It seems like I can only select one of the values to be used as the data value for the select. Is there a way I can pull more values out of the selected object to plug into my jQuery POST?

I'm not sure what would work, perhaps a way to know the selected index and then do something like (pseudo code alert) `Model.Items[7].ItemID`, `Model.Items[7].OtherID`, etc.

Edit: I think I could possibly do this...

```
@Html.DropDownList("Items", new SelectList((from i in Model.Items select new { ID = i.FirstID + "," + i.SecondID + "," + i.ThirdID, i.ItemDisplayName }), "ID", "ItemDisplayName"))
```

But then I would have to parse them out in the controller using a string split... not ideal but maybe possible?

edit: I ended up using the linq and parsing the comma delimited string I passed over, this looks like it's going to work for now but I will hold out for a better solution and selected answer on this post.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use `encodeURIComponent($('select').val())` to encode the multiple select list for form transmission:

```
$.post('<url>', { key : encodeURIComponent($('#ID').val()) }, function (data) { ... });
```

When you call `.val()` on a multiple select element that has multiple `<option>`s selected it returns an array of all the values: http://api.jquery.com/val

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/9He6s/

Comment: I think we had a communication break down, there is only one item ever selected from the list, but the item selected is an object that has multiple fields encapsulated in it.

Comment: @Ryan Can you post the HTML that gets output from the server-side code? I don't know what the code you've posted will render as...